# Docker-compose dev and prod recreated containers

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have django project. For this project i have different settings(db, ...). I want run dev and prod containers. I want to work simultaneously dev and prod. 
My structure project:

[image]

my docker-copose.yml

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: api_prod
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/django/app/
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file: env/main.env
    command: bash django_run.sh

  nginx:
    build: nginx
    container_name: ng_prod
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/api.conf
      - .:/usr/django/app/
    depends_on:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web
```

my docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: api_dev
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/django/app_dev/
    expose:
      - "8001"
    env_file: env/dev.env
    command: bash django_run.sh

  nginx:
    build: nginx
    container_name: ng_dev
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/dev_api.conf
      - .:/usr/django/app_dev/
    depends_on:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update

# Install wkhtmltopdf
RUN curl -L#o wk.tar.xz https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz \
    && tar xf wk.tar.xz \
    && cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin \
    && cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin \
    && rm wk.tar.xz \
    && rm -r wkhtmltox

RUN apt-get install -y cron

# create directory for application source code
RUN mkdir -p /usr/django/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/django/app/
COPY django_run.sh /usr/django/app/

WORKDIR /usr/django/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update

# Install wkhtmltopdf
RUN curl -L#o wk.tar.xz https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz \
    && tar xf wk.tar.xz \
    && cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin \
    && cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin \
    && rm wk.tar.xz \
    && rm -r wkhtmltox

RUN apt-get install -y cron

# create directory for application source code
RUN mkdir -p /usr/django/app_dev

COPY requirements.txt /usr/django/app_dev/
COPY django_run.sh /usr/django/app_dev/

WORKDIR /usr/django/app_dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

i run for prod commands like this:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

for dev i run commands like this:

```
docker-compose —file docker-compose.dev.yml build
docker-compose —file docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

My qestion: I want to work simultaneously and dev and prod containers, but when i run my commands higher prod containers overwrites dev. I spen many-many 
times((

Comment: Did you try to open two terminals and run the prod conf in one and the dev one in the other?

Comment: @Pawamoy thnks for comment. Yes, I tried. But still overwrites the containers

Comment: you cant start tho docker-compose from same folder. because docker-compose just creates containers with `foldername_service_1` and that is why it recreates that... you need to start them from different folder... or try to use `docker stack`

Comment: my solution it start docker-compose whith `p`, like this: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p prod up`